# Sort JSON table by Value

Tags: jquery, json, sorting

I want to sort my JSON table by the Value data.FuelState.

Unfortionally it turns back, that data.sort is no function. Whats wrong? Is the basis sort function correct?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
//..//
</head>

<body>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    function callJSON() {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $.getJSON('./url.php', function(data) {
                $("#usertable").empty();
                data.sort(function(a,b) {
                    return parseFloat(b.fuelState) - parseFloat(a.fuelState);
                });

                var cars = data.rec.vehicles.vehicles;
                $.each(cars, function(key, data){
                    //..//
                    $('#usertable').append(
                        function() {
                            return "<tr class="+farbe+">" +
                                   "<td><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-user'></span> "+data.carName+"</td>" +
                                   //..//
                                   "<tr>"; 
                        }
                    );
                });
            }).always(callJSON);
        }, 2000);
    }
    $(callJSON);
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

JSON:

```
{"err":[],"msg":[],"state":null,"rec":{"vehicles":{"search_criteria":[{"auto":"N","group":"BMW","model":"BMW 1er "},{"auto":"N","group":"MINI","model":"MINI Cooper"},{"auto":"Y","group":"BMW","model":"BMW 1er "},{"auto":"Y","group":"MINI","model":"MINI Cooper"},{"auto":"N","group":"MINI","model":"MINI Clubman"},{"auto":"Y","group":"","model":" ActiveE "},{"auto":"N","group":"MINI","model":"MINI Cabrio"},{"auto":"Y","group":"BMW","model":"BMW X1 "},{"auto":"N","group":"BMW","model":"BMW X1 "},{"auto":"Y","group":"BMW","model":"BMW ActiveE "},{"auto":"N","group":"BMW","model":"BMW 1er Cabrio"},{"auto":"Y","group":"MINI","model":"MINI Clubman"},{"auto":"N","group":"MINI","model":"MINI Coup\u00e9"},{"auto":"Y","group":"MINI","model":"MINI Coup\u00e9"},{"auto":"N","group":"BMW","model":"BMW ActiveE "}],"statistics":[],"vehicles":[{"position":{"latitude":"48.055301944444","longitude":"11.607825833333","address":"Inselkammerstra\u00dfe 4, 82008 Unterhaching"},"vin":"WBAUD71000P448627","int":"12166478","auto":"N","carName":"Fausto","cit":"7586","color":"ALPINWEISS","fuelState":"21","fuelType":"DDE","group":"BMW","innerCleanliness":"CLEAN","licensePlate":"M  -N  2651","pgid":"0","model":"BMW 1er ","cd":"0","milliageMetricsName":"0","address":"Inselkammerstra\u00dfe 4, 82008 Unterhaching","personalName":"BMW 1er : Fausto","price":{"drive":"31","park":"10"}},{"position":{"latitude":"52.541172777778","longitude":"13.325585833333","address":"Saatwinkler Damm 15-17, 13627 Berlin"}
```

Comment: Is there any reason that you haven't accepted any of the answers for your questions .

Comment: Please show us example of your JSON data

Comment: Is `$ data.sort` (note the blank) a typo?

Comment: It was a typo yes :) ... now it sais $data is not defined.

Comment: Your provided JSON doesn't match your code (you don't have a property "fuelState", how do you expect to sort on it?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data is your full JSON sample, which is an object that hold other data and the vihicles are only asub creteria of it.

The actual cars can be found under

```
data.rect.vehicles.vehicles
```

(the one which you assigned cars to)

So applying the sort function to cars works:

```
        var cars = data.rec.vehicles.vehicles;

        cars.sort(function(a,b) {
            return parseFloat(b.fuelState) - parseFloat(a.fuelState);
        });
```

Comment: Do you have a working solution for alphabetical sorting by data.model? :)